# What is the difference in meaning between "have a seat" and "get a seat"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "have a seat" and "get a seat" in the following sentence

:: source :  Alexander and the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day by JUDITH VIORST

> In the car pool Mrs. Gibson let Becky have a seat by the window.
>   Audrey and Elliott got seats by the window too.

?

What is the difference in meaning between "Mrs. Gibson let Becky have a seat by the window" and "Mrs. Gibson let Becky get a seat by the window" ?

What is the difference in meaning between "Audrey and Elliott got seats by the window" and "Audrey and Elliott had seats by the window"

Comment: Think of the second sentence as meaning: _Audrey and Elliott **were lucky enough to get** seats by the window, too._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have a seat" is generally either an offer (e.g. "Please, have a seat") or direction/instruction (e.g. "You're late; have a seat"; "Take a seat" is interchangeable for either example.

"He/she had a seat" isn't ordinarily the same as using *got* or *took* - it's more typical for *had* to be used in a more complex phrase, like "He/she had [a seat] reserved ahead of time", or for something that is consumed, like "He/she had a drink."

- The strangeness would be even more pronounced with "They had seats [by the window]" - without additional context, this implies that at some point, they *were in possession of* said seats, or that they are/were *already seated* in those seats, but isn't technically stating the *act of acquiring* the seats;

  - whereas "He/she took a seat"/"They took seats" is quite normal, and is completely interchangeable with "He/she got a seat"/"They got seats" (with or without specifying the location of the seats).  Both of these clearly convey the act of acquiring, but *had* normally refers to an acquisition that has *already occurred*.

Additionally, "Get seats" or "Get a seat" would be most appropriate to a request/direction given by Person A to Person(s) B(+) in a situation where

- seats are not assigned, i.e. 'general admission' or 'first-come-first-served';
- Person B will be arriving sooner than Person A

Hence, "Quickly, go get seats while I park the car" or "Would you mind getting us some seats near the aisle?"  (*Save* and *grab* are also frequently used in this context.)

Comment: what is the meaning of "said" in the sentnence, "they were in possession of said seats" ? does it mean "they were in possession of seats that is said" ?

Comment: That use of "said" is a synonym for "aforementioned" :)  Sorry - I would have been clearer if I had typed "the seats in question" or "the seats that we're talking about".